# Mouse pointer becoming visible in fullscreen applications

Tags: macos, mouse, fullscreen

There are some fullscreen applications which hide the default mouse pointer, such as movie players (MPlayerX, VLC), screen sharing client, some games, etc.

On my computer in many of these applications the mouse pointer re-appears after a while, which can be very annoying.  This has not been always so, and I am not sure what triggered this behaviour.

Has anyone seem similar behaviour and have you managed to find the cause?  Do you have any suggestions on how to track down the problem?

---

This situation has existed on my computer when I used 10.8 and it continues through 10.9.1.  I tried quitting all programs that run in the background, suspecting that one of them is knocking the pointer back into visibility, but this didn't help.

Comment: I know this might sound silly, but have you tried lowering the sensitivity of the mouse?

Comment: @DanijelJ The problem is not that the mouse gets accidentally moved. In some programs (screen sharing, games) the pointer should not reappear when the mouse is moved, but after a while it does and it obscures the view.  (Otherwise for e.g. movie players your guess is reasonable.)

Comment: Similar problem here (OS X 10.10 and 10.11): VLC sometimes and HTML videos (using chrome) but not all the time. It might have something to do with focus, It appears often when I connect over remote desktop,. Fullscreen app then lose focus so the OS wont hide it. But I didn't find a solution for this, I believe its one of those few VERY irritating Mac's glitches in otherwise so nice and smooth OS. One would say they will hire ppl who test and find those problems and finally god damn solve them. Why do I have to keep 5+ apps installed and programmed to remove schoolgirl errors...